# jquery-3.5.1.min.js throwing Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am upgrading the jQuery version from 1.8.1 to the latest 3.5.1 in an ASP.NET web application.

The application works if I use reference `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` but fails if I use the downloaded Nuget version of jQuery path, `<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`.

Below is the code snippet.

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="FooterContent" runat="server">
        <%--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>--%>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/js.cookie-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if (Cookies.get("RedirectToLoginPage") == "1") {
            Cookies.remove("RedirectToLoginPage");
        }
     });
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: The error you're describing usually means you're getting an error HTML page (probably with the wrong status code of 200 or 302), rather a JavaScript file. I'd start with checking the developer console in your browser.

Comment: Its a javascript error from console. Uncaught syntax error.: Unexpected Token '<'                    jQuery-3.5.1.min.js is the error. Its throwing from the local downloaded version of scripts\ jQuery-3.5.1.min.js file

Comment: @Tomalak, No. Its nota syntax error. I just kept the ajax.googleapis.com version of library as commented out for reference. I tried after removing that commented out line as well.